# In Python, how can I split a .txt file and store just the sections that I want in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, text, split

I'm very new to coding, and I saw a few similar questions on SO but none really addressed the questions I have.
I started this as a learning exercise, thinking it would be a relatively easy task, but I'm having more trouble than I thought I would.

If I have a .txt document which has several situations where something like this occurs:

> The following answer is acceptable: 
>  caía

I'm trying to figure out how to split the string and add just the answer to a list.

If I were only dealing with the one string, would it go something like this?

```
    txt = """
    The following answer is acceptable: 
    caía

    more stuff down here...
    """
    list = []
    try = txt.split(": ") # I know this is wrong...  
    # How can I get from the colon (or newline) to the end of the answer?
    list.append(try)
```

I can't really figure out how to grab from the beginning of the answer to the end of the answer and put it in a list.
To make it more complicated (at least to me), since I'm working with a .txt file with 6 or 7 answers like this, I need to figure out how to add all the answers to the list. I'm guessing I need some sort of loop? Use txt.readlines to split line by line? Or something I'm just not currently familiar with...

Also, my plan was to often switch out different sets of text in the .txt file.  The syntax would always remain the same, but the number of answers would vary, so I know I would need to figure out how to get the program to recognize that there are n number of answers and that it should add all of the answers to that list I was talking about, until it reached the end of the document.

I know this site is pretty strict about questions, so I think I'm abiding by all of the rules.  I'm just learning this stuff and it's really hitting my passion-bone.  I don't really have anyone experienced to learn from, and learning from books leaves me with a lot of questions.  I hope this is ok.

Comment: How do you know when an answer is over? Is there an empty line?

Comment: you shouldn't use *list* and *try* as variable names these are reserved words.

Comment: as @monkut stated `list` and `try` as variables will have python throwing a fit over your code if you really with to have those as variables just add an underscore after them: `list_` & `try_`  

also as @mtth stated you need a character so that you know when to stop adding answers to to list or does the list go to the end of the file?

Comment: please add a more complete example with the output you want, at the moment it is hard to see what exactly do you want achieve...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that line before the answer is only single line

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open('some.txt')]
nlines=[]
for line in lines:
    if line[-1]==':': 
        nlines.append(':'+line)
    else:
        nlines.append(line)
total="\n".join(nlines)
temp=total.split(':')
answers=temp[2::2]
for ans in answers:print ans
```

some.txt

```
first answer:
first line 1
second line 1
third line 1
second answer:
first line 2
secon line 2
third line 2
third answer:
first 3
second 3
third 3
fourth answer:
first 4
second 4
third 4
fourth 4
```

output

```
first line 1
second line 1
third line 1


first line 2
secon line 2
third line 2


first 3
second 3
third 3


first 4
second 4
third 4
fourth 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating the problem. It looks like what you want to do is recognize when a line terminates with a colon and, if it does, store the value in the next line.

```
txt = """
The following answer is acceptable: 
caía

more stuff down here...
"""
results = []

chopped_up_text = txt.split('\n')
for i, line in enumerate(chopped_up_text):
    if line[-1]==":" :
        results.append(chopped_up_text[i+1])
```

This is sort of inelegant, but it works.

EDIT: Regarding questions with multiple enumerated answers:

```
txt = """
The following answer is acceptable:
answer1
answer2
answer3

more stuff down here...
"""
results = []

chopped_up_text = txt.split('\n')
n=0
while chopped_up_text:    
    line = chopped_up_text.pop(0)
    try:
        if line.strip()[-1]==":" :
            line = chopped_up_text.pop(0)
            while line not in ("\n", "", " ", None): 
                results.append(line)
                line = chopped_up_text.pop(0)
    except:
        continue
```

It's late. This code should be prettier. But you get the idea.

Comment: I don't believe this is what he is asking...

If I am not mistaken he as asking for:
`txt = """
The following answers are acceptable:
caia
something
something else
another something else
"""`